# Error using rubber to do deeply of rails app on Amazon ec2

Tags: amazon-ec2, rubber

Any ideas why I am getting the errors below when using rubber to deploy my app to amazon ec2

```
/Users/arthurt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/excon-0.25.3/lib/excon/middlewares/expects.rb:6:in `response_call': The security group 'ynotlog_production_default' does not exist in default VPC 'vpc-123abcd' (Fog::Compute::AWS::NotFound)
    from /Users/arthurt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/excon-0.25.3/lib/excon/middlewares/response_parser.rb:8:in `response_call'
    from /Users/arthurt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/excon-0.25.3/lib/excon/connection.rb:349:in `response'
    from /Users/arthurt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/excon-0.25.3/lib/excon/connection.rb:247:in `request'
    from /Users/arthurt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/fog-1.15.0/lib/fog/xml/sax_parser_connection.rb:36:in `request'
    from /Users/arthurt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/fog-1.15.0/lib/fog/core/deprecated/connection.rb:18:in `request'
    from /Users/arthurt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/fog-1.15.0/lib/fog/aws/compute.rb:425:in `_request'
    from /Users/arthurt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/fog-1.15.0/lib/fog/aws/compute.rb:420:in `request'
    from /Users/arthurt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/fog-1.15.0/lib/fog/aws/requests/compute/run_instances.rb:112:in `run_instances'
    from /Users/arthurt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/fog-1.15.0/lib/fog/aws/models/compute/server.rb:179:in `save'
    from /Users/arthurt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/fog-1.15.0/lib/fog/core/collection.rb:52:in `create'
    from /Users/arthurt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rubber-2.5.3/lib/rubber/cloud/fog.rb:30:in `create_instance'
    from /Users/arthurt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rubber-2.5.3/lib/rubber/thread_safe_proxy.rb:13:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/arthurt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rubber-2.5.3/lib/rubber/recipes/rubber/instances.rb:311:in `create_instance'
    from /Users/arthurt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rubber-2.5.3/lib/rubber/recipes/rubber/instances.rb:230:in `block (2 levels) in create_instances'
```

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs if the specified AWS security credentials are incorrect or incorrectly specified region

```
 region: us-east-1
 access_key: YOURACCESSKEY
 secret_access_key: YOURSECRETKEY
 account: 123123171238
```